# JSXCompressor Usage

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use jsxcompressor from
http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/jsxcompressor/

but before I can get anything going I hit the problem:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

My simple sample code is as below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="/jsxcompressor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(JXG.decompress("test")); 
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I know "test" isn't exactly a compressed string but just put it there for testing to begin with.

The error from the chrome js console is like this:
[image: chrome js console error messsage]

Can anyone help me with this please?
Many thanks!

Comment: Well, maybe using a non-zlib compressed string is the problem. Have you tried passing a proper value? Have a look at what `JXG.Util.Base64.decodeAsArray('test')` returns. If it looks ok, pass the result to `new JXG.Util.Unzip(result)`, call its `unzip` method, etc. It looks like `decompress` expects a Base64 encoded string. I would not expect the method to work if you pass a string that is not encoded like that.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, have just tried with a base64 encoded string but still had the same problem.  The thing is because the error is not throwing inside the functions further below I'm suspecting JXG from the first line is failing so the Util in JXG.Util might not be accessible. Could JXG be undefined so it doesn't have any properties at that point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JXG.decompress has to be fed with a base64 encoded, compressed string. Try this one:

```
document.write(JXG.decompress("eNrzSM3JyVc1clY1MijPL8pJUTVwBAA8CgXU"));
```

At the moment, gzip has to be called with compression strength equal to 9. The PHP code to get a compressed string looks like this:

```
base64_encode(gzcompress(rawurlencode(file_get_contents($filename)),9));
```

In Python it would look like this:

```
base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(urllib.quote(text), 9))
```

Comment: Thanks for the example test strings. It led me to realize that the default c# gzip compressions were the problem in the end.

Using ionic's zlib's implementation with your recommended compression level at 9 produced a compatible string for JXG in the end, 

Thanks and hope this helps others trying to use c# string compression with JXGCompressor.

Comment: Yup, the Compression strength 9 fixed it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The given answer is correct although I wanted to contribute my findings using zlib for node.js.

I was getting the same sort of error when sending my socket messages using zlib.deflate eventhough the string was base64 encoded.  Apparently the deflate method adds some zlib headers to the compressed string.  Instead, use zlib.gzip to compress the data on the server and jsxCompress will work fine.